# How to open excel sheet file which is already created programatically

Tags: android, file-handling

I already created one folder for creating xls file. I am storing all xls file in that folder. Now i want to open that file So how can i open that file.Please give me suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create an application for that, or do you simply want to open an XLS file on your android device?

There are applications for that, like for example : http://www.ksosoft.com/android-faq/234-xls-reader-android-free.html#.VGCMyfmG-Hg